# Adding an 'empty byte' to every file inside a folder?

Tags: windows, bash, md5

I want the MD5 sum of every file to be changed, I'm thinking the best/easiest option is to add a single byte to every file (jpg, mp4, mpeg, etc) in the folder.

Anyone have a script that does this on Windows or software for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Bash you can do this as follows:

```
for x in *; do printf '\0' >> $x; done
```

Note however that some formats will not expect an extra byte at the end of the file, and depending on the reader you'll be using those files may be reported as corrupt.

Comment: That seemed to do the trick! Would you know how to make the script change the files within the subfolders too?

Comment: @Aedam: `for x in \`find . -type f\`; do printf '\0' >> $x; done`

Comment: It seems to create a new file with 1kb, but not actually modify the file